# WP_Query sort by comment meta data

Tags: wp-query, comments, order

Is it possible to use the `WP_Query` class to order by comments meta data fields?

Comment: Please, [note that third party plugins are off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you could add the code you are using to the question and describe your problem with no specific WooCommerce issues, we may take look to your issue.

Comment: ok sorry didn't know that

Comment: The problem is that the ratings are saved as comment meta, see `WC_Product` class and `get_average_rating()` method for more details, AFAIK there isn't a built-in method to sort by that. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @ialocin i think it pushed me in right direction. haven't solved it yet. But i will keep looking. I've also changed the question to a more generic wordpress question

Comment: One possibility would be, look into the WC mechanism of saving the ratings and, if practicable, hook into it to save the ratings information you need to a post meta/custom field, which you then could easily use to sort by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding a hook on the action `wp_insert_comment`.

When my hook is called i calculate the average rating for each rating meta-tag of my comments. Then i add a meta tag to the post with the result

I can use the post meta-tag to sort with `wp-query`